# jQuery selection behaviour on arrays of DOM elements

Tags: jquery, dom, attributes, css-selectors

Assuming a query as such.

```
var result = $(".ui-th-column");
```

This query in my case will return an array of objects as there are a number that match the selector provided.

If I then go something like.

```
result.attr("myAttributeName") == "MyExpectedValue"
```

I receive a result.

My question is this. Which element is jQuery acting on? As obviously different dom elements in this case my have different attributes yet it returns a value. Is it simply returning the value of the first element?

As a follow on to this question; assuming I now have my array of elements I wish to act on and assuming I wish to bind an event such as click to them all. Do I need to use the each operation or can I simply go

```
result.click(function () {});
```

and all my elements will be wired up?
I have tried to google this but wasn’t sure what terms to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is only getting the first element in the case of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

From: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

No, you don't have to call [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method for binding event handlers, it will attach the handler to all elements in the set.

Take a look at the [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method.

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements.

The [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method is shorthand...

> The jQuery library provides shortcut methods for binding the standard event types, such as `.click()` for `.bind('click')`.